# What's with the Generalist badge?

Tags: support, tags, badges

The description of the [Generalist badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist) reads:

> Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.

But I've provided non-wiki answers of at least 18 total score in 21 of the top 40 tags ([riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle), [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle), [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), [word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word), [rhyme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhyme), [story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story), [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem), [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle), [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy), [probability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability), [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms), [enigmatic-puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzles), [game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game), [combinatorics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics), [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual), [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence), [password](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password), [wordplay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordplay), [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars), [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia)) and haven't got this badge. Is this a bug? I should add that I haven't "only just" achieved these scores - I think I've been eligible for the Generalist badge for a week or so now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/180276):

> Only awarded to anyone after each of the 40 top tags has at least 200 questions

The 40th tag is [letter-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-sequence), which has 23 questions. Hence nobody on Puzzling is eligible to earn this badge yet.