# Generalist Countdown: ZERO!

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, site-promotion

### [We have liftoff!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist)

Thank you for your participation!

*-- A Generalist, 2020-02-18*

---

Since [we](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) are a relatively young site in the Stack Exchange network, we haven't been able to enjoy any [Generalist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges) badges at all.

It's not that we don't have people that would qualify (we do), but that particular badge has an [added stipulation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/23/generalist-badge-implemented/) that the **top 40 tags on the site must have at least 200 questions each** before any of those shiny silver badges are handed out.

This has always seemed to be far off in the future, but looks like we are finally [going to get there](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular)!

At the current count, we already have **34 tags** with the required 200 questions, and the six tags closest to the limit ([puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation), [number-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory), [game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game), [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube), [anagram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagram) and [password](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password)) are a mere **134 questions short**, in total.

The [answer below](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6668/36023) will keep updating periodically, and if you'd like to place bets on when we'll reach the mark, do drop a comment below! Juicy awards (If I can think of some) will go to the best guess (taking the time of the guess into account), and artificially manipulating the result is totally allowed, as long as it's done with great puzzles being added to the relevant tags!

Comment: How's the chess tag looking?

Comment: [chess] is already in the 34 tags ...

Comment: I think that it will happen on the 16th of January 2020 based on the current information. My money is on [tag:sudoku] overtaking [tag:password] for the 40th tag!

Comment: [Related](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3036/5373) :-)

Comment: We can get another tag over 200 if we separate [knowledge] and [trivia]. Oh, and how about a separate tag for Riley riddles? There has to be at least 200 of those. Oh, now I've got it: why not encourage people to post [open-ended] questions so we can get that tag past the 200 mark? Man, I'm full of great new ideas today.

Comment: @jafe I completely agree; it shouldn't matter if the race horse dies along the way as long as it crosses the finish line with at least some portion of the jockey still on its back :-)

Comment: The [three-dimensional] tag has gone from 50 to 67 in a month. Don't count it out of the race!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Do we really need to edit this post every few days? Once a week seems reasonable.

Comment: Maybe not add updates to someone else's post in the first place. Not a huge deal, but it kind of makes it look like you're putting words in Bass's mouth.

Comment: The updates are misleading anyway since the badge will only arrive as fast as the slowest tag to 200

Comment: @jafe that's what I thought too, for the first 7 seconds or thereabouts, after which I decided those would have been more or less exactly my own words. If only there was a way to mark a question as community wiki... now waitaminute!

Comment: @Adam It seems you have exposed my secret motive for creating this question :-)

Answer (score 9):

2019-07-04: still at **34 tags**, **128 questions to go**. Progress rate was 6 questions in 7 days.

2019-07-26: still at **34 tags**, **94 questions to go**. Progress rate was 34 questions in 22 days. Down to double digits!

2019-08-19: We've hit **35 tags!** Well done, [number-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)! **81 questions to go**. Progress rate was 13 questions in 24 days. (The other tags need to step up their game.)

2019-09-18: still at **35 tags**, **72 questions to go**. Progress rate was 9 questions in a month. A little biiiiiit better...

2019-10-07: [First page all done!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) **36 tags, 66 questions to go** on [the second page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=popular). Progress rate was 6 questions in 19 days.

2019-11-07: at **36 tags**, **60 questions to go**. Progress rate was 6 questions in a month. Stay on target...

2019-12-11: at **37 tags**, **52 questions to go**. Progress rate was 8 questions in over a month. [game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) made it to 200 questions.

2020-01-04: at **37  tags**, **23 questions to go**. Progress rate was 29 questions in 24 days. We're getting close!

2020-01-19: at **38 tags**, **15 questions to go**. Progress rate was 8 questions in 15 days. [anagram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagram) got there!

2020-02-09: at **39 tags**, **5 questions to go**. Progress rate was 10 questions in 21 days. [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube) got there! Five more [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) questions to go!

2020-02-15: at **39 tags**, **4 questions to go**.

2020-02-17: at **39 tags**, **one question to go**.

2020-02-18: at **40 tags!!!**, zero questions to go!

Answer (score 6):

The [tags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=popular) that are 'up for it' are:

[sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) 199
[situation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/situation) 182
[password](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password) 178
[crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords) 169

Note that only one more tag needs to make it to 200 for the Generalist badge to become available.